# Different unicode results between nvarchar(max) and nvarchar(4000) in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I found a strange behaviour regarding unicode handling in my MS-SQL (14.0) database when altering a column's type from NVARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(4000) and I don't know what causes it.

The table (Database collation: Latin1_General_100_CI_AS):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]([Text] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL)
```

Firstly, I manually **pasted** into "Text" "f�V" (f\ue48a\udc0bV) by using SQL Management Studio's "Edit Top 200 Rows" (don't ask why...).

[image: Select * From Test]

Then I altered the column's type:

```
ALTER TABLE Test
ALTER COLUMN Test nvarchar(4000)
```

[image: Select * From Test]

As you can see, the second unicode character is displayed differently.
This behaviour can be reversed when changing the type back to nvarchar(max) etc.

The actual problem is that when I load that entry in a C# application via EntityFramework, the resulting string reads "f\ue48a\udc0bfV" if nvarchar(max), but "f�V" if nvarchar(4000), the former causing exceptions when written to a stream.

Does anybody know what the actual difference is and why it's even there?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
This doesn't solve my problem, but the difference of the unicode handling might be coming from the NVARCHAR(MAX) values being stored in a LOB instead of NVARCHAR(4000)'s in-row storage.

**Edit2:**
Just adding that I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/381) as proposed.

Comment: No, there's no difference. The text was mangled to begin with. What you posted isn't Unicode, it's unrepresentable bytes. *THIS page* and your own post proves there's nothing wrong with SQL Server- StackOverflow is an ASP.NET site storing Unicode data in SQL Server using nvarchar columns

Comment: In fact, that `�` is the [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) used when trying to read single-byte text using the wrong codepage. Some fonts may not have that character and dispaly an empty square instead. Other drivers replace bad data with`?`. In any case, the data was lost the moment it was pasted into the grid

Comment: It is just the tool that is used to display the results and not actual characters.  The encoding that is being used to display makes the character look different.  With encoding the character 0x00 to 0x7F all look the same.  The character 0x80 to 0xFF are mapped to different unicode characters but are one byte instead of two bytes.  The byte value are still 0x80 to 0xFF but the encoding just displays the characters differently.

Comment: I understand that the replacement character is a visual thing only, yet it does change when altering the column's type. 
In addition, the resulting string in the C# part is different as well changing nothing but the column type. Hence I suspected something has to be different, otherwise I'd always get the same result.

Comment: This is an ADO.NET client issue, not a SQL Server issue. You can verify the column contents are unchanged by doing a `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` and furthermore verify that the bytes are unchanged using a packet sniffer on the TDS return packets. Exactly the same is returned for both columns, with the only difference being the metadata. Apparently, for `NVARCHAR(MAX)` it simply copies the bytes, while `NVARCHAR(4000)` is subject to a decoding step that filters out the invalid UTF-16 sequence. `sqlcmd` does not have this problem (SSMS is .NET-based as well).

Comment: If you want, you could open an issue for the new `SqlClient` repo [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient). However, this may be a decoding issue in the bottom-most (native) layer that is almost certainly not going to be changed at all, for backwards compatibility, and even in the higher layers this may not be a welcome change. Still, it can't hurt to make people aware of the difference if they're not already.

Comment: Shortest repro: `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), 0x0BDC), CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x0BDC)`. (Again, a packet sniffer will demonstrate SQL Server is *not* performing any transformation on these bytes as part of the conversion.)